# A spoken English equivalent of 'someone who has glass-dust'

Tags: idioms, translation

In my native language we have the expression *having glass-dust* by which in **spoken language** we describe a person who's generally good but sometimes gets dishonest to take advantage of a situation or does an immoral thing now and then.

> Don't trust him completely. I know him for years. *He's got glass-dust*.

Or

> He's a good bloke but he's got alittle glass-dust.

Is there a common spoken form of this expression in English? (Well I know how to use adjectives to express the idea but any spoken idiom or expression?)

I'm asking this because I was watching Southpark the episode in which Tweek & Craig were thought to be gay but they aren't so they pretend that they're breaking up in front of everyone. Tweek said,

> "I opened myself up and let you in, but **you've got spikes**, man."

It came to me that this is exactly where a person in my native language would say, "you've got glass-dust, man" to imply that you're dishonest and duplicitous.

I searched dictionaries but I didn't find anything like *have spikes* even as a spoken expression. As native speakers, do you think it's acceptable as the equivalent I'm looking for? If not, what do you suggest?

**Edit:** We say someone *has glass-dust* (in nature) as there is a piece of broken glass in food. Food is generally good but if you're not careful you can cut yourselves with that piece. I figured maybe *spikes* represents *glass-dust* in my native language. But I couldn't find anything to back that up.

Comment: I'm curious what your native language is.

Comment: Persian :) _خرده شیشه داشتن_ is the expression perhaps other Persian speakers can help.

Comment: @Cardinal [tounge-in-cheek](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tongue-in-cheek) kind of means sarcastic, or deliberately ironic or something. However thanks for that I didn't know that expression. :)

Comment: @Rompey I'm not sure I got you correct. _have spikes_ means pouring alcohol in someone's drink?!

Comment: Could it be "He's got a mean streak", I wonder. The word "streak" is used to denote a character trait.

Comment: I thought that idiom is mainly characterized by **"insincerity"**, btw, I was too hasty that I didn't check the spelling ^_^

Comment: The conversation I got it on YouTube: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xyp7ZUO_XQQ

Comment: @CowperKettle I would put that as an answer. It's worth an upvote because I can definitely use it esp. for mischievous kids. However, can I put it in the context of Craig and Tweek, too?

Comment: Yuri - feel free to post it as a "community wiki answer" that could be edited by many people, because I've no time to investigate the term now.

Comment: @Yuri - On finding the episode (you didn't provide the link) I say no, in the context "spikes" mean something very sharp, like hedgehog's needles, that make it impossible for the two to remain close to each other any longer.

Comment: I don't think the Southpark "**you've got spikes**" is remotely idiomatic - as can be inferred from the fact that *all* the first page of Google hits for that string of words are obviously Southpark-related (because it doesn't really occur elsewhere). I don't suppose the writers were consciously thinking of [Mony Python's Spring Surprise](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/37cd34f6-83bd-4908-86e1-8a48daea73fb), but that's essentially the sense being alluded to (I let you "inside" me, but your metaphorical sharp edges caused me internal damage).

Comment: There is the related idiomatic usage ***spikey** = easily offended or annoyed*, but most likely the Southpark usage wasn't intended to allude to that anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, is there any idiomatic English phrase that you suggest? Despite what Mark Ripley suggests i.e. _"He looks for the easy path"_ and _"he's got a mean streak"_ by  CowperKettle ofcourse.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see what people who "look for the easy path" have to do with things. You seem to be saying thsat in *your* language, your idiomatic reference to glass-dust alludes to the danger of sharp edges of *broken* glass that might cut you. In normal English we don't really talk about glass-dust (what you'd get if you scraped glass with a diamond nail-file, I guess). We have ***ground glass*** (crushed into tiny pieces) sterotypically used as a "poison" by Victorian would-be widows, but we wouldn't use that to metaphorically refer to a dangerous *person*.

Comment: And as for *a mean streak*, would your "glass-dust" still work if the person was "accidentally" dangerous, rather than being deliberately malicious? You have to be clear exactly what meaning you want, or we can't pin it down. After all, glass itself isn't malicious, so it certainly has no "mean streak".

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it wouldn't be accidental. If someone has _ground glass_ (as you suggested) he is **deliberately malicious and dishonest sometimes** so he's not completely honest sometimes because he seeks gaining benefit in dishonest ways.

Comment: He's **not a complete evil** though, just you should be **careful** about him. Ground glass here refers to a **small** piece of broken glass that's why it's understood in my native language as someone who's **sometimes malicious**.

Comment: [***untrustworthy***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/untrustworthy) *unreliable, treacherous, deceitful, false, tricky, slippery, untrue, dishonest, fickle, devious, unfaithful, capricious, two-faced, disloyal, faithless, fair-weather, fly-by-night (informal), undependable.* There are lots of words in that general area, which don't have much to do with the Southpark example (why exactly have you included it?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I made a guess based on the context and my native language knowledge. I kind of got excited having thought that this might be an equivalent. At the same time since I couldn't find _have spikes_ as a registered phrase I got curious about a similar phrase or idiomatic English wording for the expression in my native language. As It turns out, I need to use adjectives to transfer what I mean in English not really a special idiomatic thing. Thank you FumbleFingers for the list that you provided.

Comment: Bear in mind that the degree of correspondence between Southpark dialogue and what people *actually* say in the real world is about on a par with that between the cartoon drawings themselves and photographs of real people. Nobody really knows what *You've got spikes, man!* means - not even the authors (since it's written by several people in concert, who might all understand it differently).

Comment: What does "got" mean in "He's got glass dust"?  Is it something he wields as a weapon (He's got a knife!) Something he has in his possession?  (He's got some money in his pocket).  Something from which he suffers (he's got chicken pox)?  A trait? (He's got a wicked temper).

Comment: @TRomano Literally it means _contain_ as in _this pizza's got lots of chilly in it_ by this we mean _his nature contains small broken pieces of glass_. Figuratively it's a character trait (better to say personality trait though) as in your last example. _Small broken pieces of glass_ represents some negative character trait mainly _dishonesty_. And by _small_ we mean it's not a dominant trait that makes that person completely bad (pure evil). So literal translation is glass-dust (very small broken pieces of glass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context you gave, the statements from Southpark are related to the analogy that we all have a soft inner (emotional) self that we hide behind a hard outer protective (emotional) shell that we show to strangers. The part "you've got spikes" means that while the speaker opened himself up in the relationship, the other person's personality caused damage to him. I don't believe this is the same meaning as your phrase "he's got glass dust" in your language, since it refers to a specific kind of damage (emotional) that was caused in a specific type of relationship, and not a general tendancy to make 'bad' choices sometimes.

Instead, the phrase "He looks for the easy path" implies someone who might do the right thing, but often chooses to do the wrong thing instead (because that choice is easier for him). Another alternative is to say "he is unreliable", which implies that he may be reliable at times, but often is not, so extending trust to him is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks that was very enlightening esp the _spikes_ thing.